# request in django models.py

Tags: django, django-models, request, models

I might be a noob question but... is there a way of using request in models.py?

Something like:

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(default=request.user)
    ...other fields...
```

Or maybe using the post_init method for doing this job.

Thanks.

Comment: The request should really only be used in the view; if you feel you need the request, there is probably an easier or better way.  What specifically are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

That specific example you gave it's not useful in Django. **Request** do have a context with them (the context where the HTTP happened) so it could or could not be available when you instantiate `MyModel`.

You can do in your view:

```
def index(request):
    myModel = MyModel(request.user)
```

And in your model:

```
class MyModel (models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __init__(self, pUserName):
        self.user = User.objects.get(userName=pUserName)
```